# trying to dynamically change drupal commerce order

Tags: commerce

I am trying to create a pane on the drupal commerce checkout page which will will give the user some options to change which product is in the cart. I want this done with ajax, without leaving the checkout page.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
  global $user;
  $product_id = 3;
  $order_id = commerce_cart_order_id($user->uid);
  commerce_order_delete($order_id); //delete the present order
  $newOrder = commerce_order_new($user->uid); //and create a new one
  commerce_order_save($newOrder);   //NEED?
  $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);  
  $lineItem = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $newOrder->order_id);
  commerce_line_item_save($lineItem); //NEED?

  // Add the line item to the order using fago's rockin' wrapper.
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

  // Save the order again to update its line item reference field.
  commerce_order_save($newOrder);
  commerce_cart_order_refresh($newOrder);

  return $form;
```

However, this code gives me an ajax error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://example.com/system/ajax

Am I making a code error? A Commerce error?

Comment: Check your server logs, they will contain a proper error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going out on a limb a bit...

There's no function called `commerce_new_order`, you probably mean [`commerce_order_new()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_new/7)

Same thing with `commerce_load_product()` and [`commerce_product_load()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product!commerce_product.module/function/commerce_product_load/7)

Comment: You're right. I changed that, an now I get a different error pop up: An AJAX HTTP error occured: Debugging information follows. Path /system/ajax StatusText: error ResponseText: EntityMetadataWrapperException: MIssing data values. in EntityMetadataWrapper-&gt;value() line 83 etc

Comment: It doesn't look like you've initialised the `$order` variable

Comment: your right, edited that above. But still have the same error.

Comment: You still haven't initialised an `$order` variable. The problems you're having are all to do with incorrectly named variables. Do yourself a favour - delete the code you have, and start again from fresh, paying close attention to the names of the variables you're creating, and how you're then using them

Comment: sorry, did a full edit now. I think it might work, just not sure yet because I think I have some rules set up which are messing with the order as well.

Comment: But is this the correct way of doing things? Is there a way to delete the products inside of an order without actually deleting the order?

Comment: Personally I'd just remove the line item from the existing order, rather than making a whole new order. Have a look at [`commerce_cart_order_empty()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_empty/7) and [`commerce_cart_order_product_line_item_delete()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21cart%21commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_product_line_item_delete/7) for some inspiration

Comment: Perfect, thats exactly what I need! One more question: I was trying to copy someone else's example. Would I really need both commerce_line_item_save() and commerce_order_save() if I just update a previous order? Wouldn't the former be enough, since I gave it the order id?

Comment: Saving the order won't save the referenced entities, no (or at least in my experience it doesn't)